# Why Grails use Ivy as build and dependency manager?

Tags: grails, gradle, ivy

There is a great builder/dependency manager Gradle written in Groovy, so why Grails framework uses Ivy as its dependency manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's planned for version 3.0 - see http://grails.org/Roadmap